# Ruby wrapping timeout method

Tags: ruby, timer, wrapper, ruby-1.9.3

I can implement a timeout method for my sorting like this:

```
  def timed_sort(seconds=1, &block)
    Timeout::timeout(seconds) { quick_sort &block }
    rescue Timeout::Error
      raise Exception.new( "The process timed out")
  end
```

However, looking to improve my coding style (mostly for re-usability) I was trying to create a generic class for such timeouts so I would be able to call:

```
a = [1,4,2,5]
a.timed_out(1).quick_sort
```

My current attempt was:

```
Class Array
  def self.timed_out(seconds = 10)
      Timer.new(self, seconds)
  end
End

class Timer
  attr_reader :seconds, :object
  def initialize(object, seconds)
    @seconds = seconds
    @object = object
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    Timeout::timeout(seconds) { object.send(name, *args, &block) }
  rescue Timeout::Error
    raise StandardError.exception("The process timed out")
  end
end
```

When I try to call  `a.timed_out.quick_sort` I get:

> undefined method `timed_out'

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Does the code work? If yes, what specifically are you wanting feedback on ( if a full code review is what you want, I suggest http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ )? If no, please give more details about what is wrong.

Comment: @NeilSlater Edited, hope itś more clear now.

Comment: `def self.timed_out(seconds = 10)` defines `Array.timed_out` . . . remove the `self.` if you want an instance method as per your test.

Comment: @NeilSlater, thank you. I just used `def timed_out(seconds = 10)` then returned `self` in that function and it worked as expected.